# Is it possible to check if a variable is equal to window object or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do an example:

```
let var1 = window;

if(var1 == window){
    //do something
}
```

Will it operate good?

Not asking this:

```
let a = {c: 'a'};
let b = {c: 'a'};

if(a == b){
// do something
}
```

There is a list in responsive page. When the page is loaded, if page width lower than 768px function gets window object for detect scroll position like this:

```
if((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) < 768){
  flowObj.scrollElement = window;
}else{
  flowObj.scrollElement = document.querySelector('.flow-list').parentNode;
}
// If width lower than 768px list-container CSS change to height: auto; scroll: none; so list scroll on body
```

Need to change scroll position with this:

```
if(flowObj.scrollElement == window){
 flowObj.scrollElement.scrollTo(0, value);
}else {
 flowObj.scrollElement.scrollTop = value;
}
```

Need to know is it working good?

Comment: Why not just try it? In any case, JS does reference comparison, e.g., if two references "point" to the same object.

Comment: You asked the question again with the reason why this time I see.

Comment: What ever object we create in JS it's under `window` object. like a global variable `var a;` is also `window.a`. What you are trying to do move courser with window width is possible via CSS.

Comment: code working good actually but I am curious about technique is right or wrong

Comment: You should try to replace this logic with CSS media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @NAVIN OP is asking whether or not you can compare a value with `window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let var1 = window;`

Var1 is a reference pointing at the window object. That is, you only have a "key" to the window object itself. As long as you don't change var1's value, a shallow comparison with window will always return true

On the other hand, if you try to make a deep copy of the window object, it will get tricky because the window object changes over time, but the object you created by deep cloning won't.